# How to rewrite a value in a record set with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

For example, this way get `Photo` records:

```
return DB::table('photos')->skip(1)->take(2)->get();
```

Return these data:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  name  |   photo    |
|----|--------|------------|
| 1  | flower | flower.jpg |
| 2  | grass  | grass.jpg  |
...
```

Want to rewrite `photo` column data as this record set:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------+
| id |  name  |          photo               |
|----|--------|------------------------------|
| 1  | flower |  https://my-site/flower.jpg  |
| 2  | grass  |  https://my-site/grass.jpg   |
...
```

Is there a simple way to do?

Comment: use url(); and concate it with your image name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-concat) method :

```
DB::table('photos')->select('id','name',DB::raw("CONCAT('https://my-site/', 'photo') as photo")->skip(1)->take(2)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [`Accessor`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Define this method in your `Photo` model

```
/**
 * Get the photo's path.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhotoAttribute($value)
{
    return asset($value);
}
```

then you could try

```
return Photo::skip(1)->take(2)->get();
```